# How to download swf with the contents it downloads?

Tags: flash, download

I want to get a flash game that loads the contents of the game. When i download the swf, it's just the loader so it's useless. I need the full contents. How do i achieve this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I can put the link to the link of the file i'm working on if it's allowed. But for example, a miniclip game, the initial swf, the loader, is about 50 KB, but then it loads a lot of content, for example the music, graphics, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a HttpWatch, and sniff what the loader loaded, and download what you want by according to HttpWatch's record.